# Configuring New Relic custom metrics with YAML

Tags: java, monitoring, newrelic

According to the [New Relic Documentation](http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-monitoring-by-xml):

> Starting in version 2.10.0, you can monitor specific methods in your application without modifying code by using a custom instrumentation XML file.

It also says:

> Prior to 2.10.0, YAML files could be used for custom instrumentation. These YAML files are still supported.

I can't find documentation for the YAML format anywhere.  I'm assuming it's pretty similar to the XML structure, but it can't be a 1-to-1 match.

"Where can I find documentation" seems like a terrible Stack Overflow question, so here is specifically what I want to know.  Given the following Java class:

```java
public class Test {
    public void foo() {
        bar();
    }

    private void bar() {
    }
}
```

What New Relic YAML configuration would I use to track both foo and bar where foo is a transaction entry point and bar is not (assuming I inferred the meaning of that attribute correctly)?

Thanks a lot!
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the folks over at New Relic.  The documentation regarding the yml configuration has been removed because it has been deprecated.  The old yml configuration support is there for backward compatibility; however, new features have been added to the xml configuration that are not supported by the yml configs . . . for example, method matching without parameter specifications.

The supported approach to custom extensions is to use the XML configuration.  A few notes from my experience in case it helps someone else with similar problems.

The [custom xml examples](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-xml-examples) documentation at the time of writing has a sample that's invalid if you try to validate it with the command mentioned in the [custom monitoring by xml](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-monitoring-by-xml) document.

Here's a sample script that worked for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension 
    xmlns="https://newrelic.com/docs/java/xsd/v1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="newrelic-extension extension.xsd " 
    name="HelloWorldExtension" version="1.0"
  >
  <instrumentation>
    <pointcut transactionStartPoint="true">
      <className>com.autopilotllc.HelloWorld</className>
      <method>
        <name>sayHello</name>
      </method>
    </pointcut>
  </instrumentation>
</extension>
```